# What is the best algorithm to find the longest double monotonically increasing sub-sequence of a sequence of n numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, computer-science

I've seen some discussion about longest monotonically increasing sub-sequence algorithm. But my case is a little bit different.

The double increasing sub-sequence is defined as this:
The first part and second part of the sub-sequence are both monotonically increasing sub-sequences.

For example:

the sequence 10,19,8,12 is;

the sequence 10,19,28,33 is;

the sequence 10,19,28,28 is;

the sequence 10,19,8,2 not;
the sequence 10,19,8,8 not

another sequence that satisfy the condition is:

1,3,5,7,9,10, 6,9,11,17,28,30;

so the first part 1,3,5,7,9,10 is strictly monotonically increasing; and the same for the second part 6,9,11,17,28,30.
The original sequence  maybe something like:

**1**,99,**3**,98,**5**,97,**7**,96,**9**,95,**10**, **6**,89,**9**,88,**11**,87,**17**,86,**28**,85,**30**

Can we find a little-o(n^2)-time algorithm?

Comment: How 10,19,28,28 "is", and 10,19,8,8 "is not"?

Comment: (@user1990169: 10,19,8,8 "is not" (double) _strictly_ increasing.) (Oops - fell for subsequence not neccessarily consecutive. Again.)

Comment: (the first "**bold** subsequence" in the "original sequence" example is not maximal (could include 94 - 7 to 9 would separate the two increasing subsequences nicely)) -> Are there restrictions on the elements of the original sequence that make up the subsequences in addition to _strictly increasing_ (and no element in both, presumably)? What about 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7? 1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5?

Comment: @greybeard sorry I modified again. And I believe user2040251 has provided a valuable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is even possible to get an O(n log n) solution. Let's assume that we have computed the length of the longest increasing subsequence that ends somewhere to the left(inclusively) from i for each i and the length of the longest decreasing subsequence in a reversed array that to the right from i(not including i). Then the answer is the lagrest sum of these two values for all i. It can be done in O(n log n) time because all what you have to do is to run standard algorithm for computing the longest increasing/decreasing subsequence twice and then make a couple of linear passes.

Comment: Excellent idea! But I still have some confusion. I agree that increasing/decreasing two computations take O(nlogn), then you still don't know where is the correct point i. So you need to loop i from 1 to n to find the best one. Thus T~O(n^2 logn). Am I correct?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis You first make these two computations in `O(n log n)` and then you loop from 1 to n(they are not nested). So it `O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`, not `O(n log n) * O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out!